# API does not return anything except for metadata object

Tags: nest-api

Was hoping someone could help me with this.

I've created a new "product" on developer.nest.com and gave it ***all*** available permissions with ***read/write*** access where available. My product is using *code* authentication, so after following all steps to get the code, it was time to make some requests.

When I got the "Exchange the authorization code for an access token" of the [walkthrough](https://developers.nest.com/documentation/cloud/rest-quick-guide), I did not get anything other than the ***metadata*** object. There was nothing about my devices or structures.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using real or simulated devices? Do you have devices on the account?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @urman! Yes, I do have a device on the account (and I can see it fro the web interface)

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to make the call?

Comment: No code. Was using postman to make those calls by hand.

Comment: Please post the call you made leaving out the token.

Comment: Here's the equivalent of what I did with Postman using curl: `curl -XGET -L -H "Authorization: Bearer blah blah blah" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://developer-api.nest.com` and as a response, I got this: `{"metadata":{"access_token":"c.some_very_long_token","client_version":1}}`

Comment: What happens if you get a new token?

Comment: Same thing. Here's what I've tried thus far: At least 5 different tokens; At least 3 different 'Products'; Created a new developer account. All my attempts result in the same response...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely authorizing the Works with Nest connection using a [Family Account](https://developers.nest.com/documentation/cloud/family-accounts/).  Only the home "owner" can currently access the Nest structures and associated devices.

Comment: Yes, I was using a family account. Just tested it with the 'owner' account and got all the data I needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The ***metadata*** object is not part of  "Exchange the authorization code for an access token" flow.  If you are seeing ***metadata*** you must've received an access token and made an API request to https://developer-api.nest.com.  This is where you would see the ***metadata*** object.  As part of the "Exchange the authorization code for an access token" your response should be an access token and expiration, e.g.

{
"access_token": "c.FmDPkzyzaQe...",
"expires_in": 315569260
}

Comment: Correct, I am getting the token and expiration. However, when I call **GET** with that token, i do not get anything other than the **metadata** object.